# Retrieving Content-Length using apache httpClient 4.5.x

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using apache httpClient and I understand that if the response headers is missing the Content-Length,

```
closeableHttpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength()
```

will return -1.

However, when debugging, I am intrigued by intelliJ wrappedEntity object which appears to be holding the Content-Length value. Is wrappedEntity something that intelliJ is implementing on it's side(internally)? If so, I imagine it's not accessible via my application code. 
How hard would it be implement wrappedEntity? Any pointers would be appreciated!

[image: intellij-debug]

Comment: `wrappedEntity` is a field name. It' s type is most likely`org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ResponseEntityProxy`. Why would you want to re-implement that?

Comment: @ralf I need the Content-Length, appears like header doesn't have it most of the time for reasons I understand.Thus exploring my options.

Comment: The content length header is set by the server, if it knows the length of the response. But a server is free to not set the content length. Instead the server normally sets the `Transfer-Encoding` header to `chunked`. And there is nothing you can do about it on the client side.